# Using the monero cli on ubuntu. How do I set it to use a remote node?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, remote-access

I'm using monero-cli on ubuntu and i want to have it connect to a remote node instead of downloading the entire blockchain. How can I do this? Where can I get a list of remote nodes?